# Oracle connection error

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ioexception

> java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the
>    connection at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java)

I am getting this error when data in database is increased (nearly 3000). It works fine with limited data (say 100).

Comment: We need more than that to tell what's going on.  Can you post some code?

Comment: What do you mean with data is increased (nearly 3000). Do you mean that the exception occurs when you grow the database by 3000G in one transaction? To you insert 3000 rows in one bulk insert? At the moment your question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Is typically thrown when

- the Oracle listener is not running
- the wrong hostname was specified in the connection url
- the wrong port was specified in the connection url
- the port is blocked by firewall

I have never seen it related to "increasing" the data in the database